# Sign extend a nine-bit number in C

Tags: c

I have a short, `instr`, that looks like this:

```
1110xxx111111111
```

I need to pull out bits 0-9, which I do with `(instr & 0x1FF)`. This quantity is then stored in a new short. The problem is that when this occurs, it becomes `0x0000000111111111`, not `0x1111111111111111` like I want. How can I fix this? Thanks!

## EDIT

Here's the code:

```
short instr = state->mem[state->pc];
unsigned int reg = instr >> 9 & 7; // 0b111
state->regs[reg] = state->pc + (instr & 0x1FF);
```

This is a simulator that reads in assembly. `state` is the machine, `regs[]` are the registers and `pc` is the address of the current instruction in `mem[]`.

This is fine if the last nine bits represent a positive number, but if they're representing -1, it's stored as all 1's, which is interpreted as a positive value by my code.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question or the process you're using. Care to share the code you're using to get these results?

Comment: This is not clear, who should become `0x1111111111111111`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming a short is 16 bits:

You can do it manually:  `(instr & 0x1FF) | ((instr & 0x100) ? 0xFE00 : 0)`.  This tests the sign bit (the uppermost bit you are retaining, `0x100`) and sets all the bits above it if the sign bit is set.  You can extend this to 5 bits by adapting the masks to `0x1F`, `0x10` and `0xFFE0`, being the lower 5 bits, the 5th bit itself and all the bits 5-16 respectively.

Or you can find some excuse to assign the bits to the upper part of a signed short and shift them down (getting a sign-extension in the process): `short x = (instr & 0x1FF) << 7; x >>= 7;`  The latter may actually end up being more straightforward in assembly and will not involve a branch.  If `instr` is *signed* this can be done in a single expression:  `(instr & 0x1FF) << 7 >> 7`.  Since that already removes the upper bits it simplifies to `instr << 7 >> 7`.  Replace 7 with 11 for 5 bits (16-5).

Comment: How might this be adapted for a 5-bit number? I need to handle both types in this program.

Comment: On the latter, couldn't you just do `(instr & 0x1FF << 7) >> 7`?

Comment: +1, but while shifting left then shifting right should work (so long as you're using a signed type), but I wouldn't be surprised if some relatively obscure compilers (perhaps on embedded platforms) incorrectly optimise that away, assuming that the two shifts will cancel out and failing to notice the sign-extending side-effect. I mention this because the style of code seems most likely to be occur with an embedded platform when extracting a value from a hardware register.

Comment: @Steve314: True, but if it works it will probably generate the fastest code!  With iffy compilers like that I tend to double check the assembly anyway.  Even when they're correct, sometimes they do ridiculous things and you have to tweak the code until you find a smarter part of the compiler.

Comment: @Ben Jackson, @Steve314 is right to worry about that signed right shift.  The result of signed right shift is not defined by the standard.  Of course your first solution works--as long as you accept OP's premise that `short` is 16 bits (also not guaranteed).

Comment: @BenJackson the following is slightly shorter to read and independent of word-size: `(instr & 0x1FF) | -(instr & 0x100)`.

Answer (score 30):

*** No branching required ***

See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#FixedSignExtend for a list of very useful bit hacks. Specifically, sign extending a number is as simple as:

```
/* generate the sign bit mask. 'b' is the extracted number of bits */
int m = 1U << (b - 1);  

/* Transform a 'b' bits unsigned number 'x' into a signed number 'r' */
int r = (x ^ m) - m;
```

You may need to clear the uppermost bits of 'x' if they are not zero ( `x = x & ((1U << b) - 1);` ) before using the above procedure.

If the number of bits 'b' is known at compile time (e.g., 5 bits in your case) there's even a simpler solution (this might trigger a specific sign-extend instruction if the processor supports it and the compiler is clever enough):

```
struct {signed int x:5;} s;
r = s.x = x;
```

Comment: GCC tends to warn about the struct bitfield assignment, unfortunately.

Comment: Change `x = x & ((1U << b) - 1);` to `x = x & ((1UL << b) - 1);` for larger than 32 bits on some systems.  Caught this while doing sign extension on large datasets under googletest, figure I'd save someone a minute.

Answer (score 4):

```
(instr & 0x1FF) * (1 - ((unsigned short)(instr & 0x100) >> 7))
```

How does it work?  It selects your sign bit and shifts it to the 2's position.  This is used to generate either the value 1 (if your sign bit was absent) or -1 (if your sign bit was present).

This solution is branchless and does not depend on undefined behavior.

Comment: On an unknown microcontroller I'd probably err on the side of branching rather than multiplying.  The branch penalty on such CPUs is small and the penalty if there's no hardware multiplier (or maybe even if there is!) is much higher.  In fact, given the risk of no *barrel shifter* perhaps the simple branch/test is best.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a refinement of previous answers but no fully generic solution has been presented so far. This macro will sign extend a value `v` with `sb` indicating the 0-based bit number of the sign bit.

```
#define SIGNEX(v, sb) ((v) | (((v) & (1 << (sb))) ? ~((1 << (sb))-1) : 0))

int32_t x;

SIGNEX(x, 15); // Sign bit is bit-15 (16th from the right)
SIGNEX(x, 23); // Sign bit is bit-23 (24th from the right)
```

It uses branching to maximize portability across platforms that lack a hardware multiply or barrel shifter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're getting 13 1 bits after masking with `0x1ff`, but this should sign-extend a 9-bit number into a 16-bit short.  Not pretty (or particularly efficient), but it works:

```
(instr & 0x1ff) | (0xfe00 * ((instr & 0x100) >> 8))
```

Mask out the sign bit, shift to the 1 position to get 0/1.  Multiply this by the the upper bits, if the sign is 1, then the 9-bit number will be OR'ed with `0xfe`, which will set all the upper bits to 1.

Comment: Haven't tested this yet, but how could this be adapted for a 5-bit number? I need to get both types in this program. And you're right about the results; I've been working for hours, so I'm exhausted. :D

Comment: Mask out the sign bit and shift that bit to the 1's position (so you get 1 if you have a negative number and 0 otherwise).  Then create an OR-mask for the extended bits and multiply this by the shifted sign.  If your original number was negative, this mask will stay all ones, and otherwise will be all zeros.  OR this with your masked number to fill the upper bits with 1's.

Answer (score 2):

Just bumped into this looking for something else, maybe a bit late, but maybe it'll be useful for someone else. AFAIAC all C programmers should start off programming assembler.

Anyway sign extending is much easier than the other 2 proposals. Just make sure you are using signed variables and then use 2 shifts.

```
short instr = state->mem[state->pc];
unsigned int reg = (instr >> 9) & 7; // 0b111
instr &= 0x1ff;  // get lower 9 bits
instr = ((instr << 7) >> 7); // sign extend
state->regs[reg] = state->pc + instr;
```

If the variable is signed then the C compiler translates >> to Arithmetic Shift Right which preserved sign. This behaviour is platform independent.

So, assuming that instr starts of with 0x1ff then we have, << 7 will SL (Shift Left) the value so instr is now 0xff80, then >> 7 will ASR the value so instr is now 0xffff.

Comment: Is "instr &= 0x1ff;  // get lower 9 bits" needed in this context? These bits are pushed away anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution is this, for `x` being a **5-bit 2**'s complement number, look:

```
z = (x^16)-16
```

Comment: Yep.  https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#VariableSignExtend

Answer (score 0):

*Not the most optimal, but arguably easy to read solution*:

To sign extend the 9-bit value, you can replace

```c
(instr & 0x1FF)
```

... with ...

```c
((instr & 0x1FF) | -(instr & 0x100))
```

or

```c
((instr & 0x0FF) | -(instr & 0x100))
```

.

### Explanation

In 2s-complement arithmetic, `(instr & 0x100)` will isolate the sign bit and negating it with `-(instr & 0x100)` will effectively sign-extend the isolated sign bit.  Finally OR the sign-extended sign bit with the original value (with or without its sign bit) to obtain the sign extension: `((instr & 0x1FF) | -(instr & 0x100))` or `((instr & 0x0FF) | -(instr & 0x100))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would sign extend 9 bits to 16 bits.

```
int16_t x = (int16_t)(instr << 6) >> 6;
```

Or like this:

```
int16_t x = (instr & 0x100) ? (int16_t)inst - 0x200 : (int16_t)inst;
```