# How do I convert binary number to signed decimal

Tags: c

Suppose that I have this binary number "1011" and I want to convert it to signed decimal so it is "-3" not "11". How do I do that I C.

Comment: You have a 4-bit signed integer data type?

Comment: Sign-extend to whatever size `int` is, and store that value in a variable. Done.

Comment: Well, both [manual sign extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5814072/11683) and [`struct {signed int x:4;}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719010/11683) give -5, not -3.

Comment: I might miss calculate

Comment: You are using the 'normal' 2's complement for negative values or thinking of [Signed magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation_(SMR))?

Comment: You have what??

Answer (score 0):

decimal, binary, hexadecimal, octal... is just a matter of string representation; the integer value (stored in an `int` variable for example) stays the same whatever the base we use.

For example

```
int a=33;   // understood as decimal representation by the compiler
int b=0x21; // understood as hexadecimal representation by the compiler
int c=041;  // understood as octal representation by the compiler
int d='!';  // understood as ASCII representation by the compiler
if((a==b)&&(a==c)&&(a==d))
{
  printf("this condition is always true!\n");
}
```

Then, we can assume from the question that `"1011"` is a string representation of a 4-bit signed integer expressed in base 2 and that we want to produce another string containing the representation of the same value expressed in base 10.

Assuming we rely on the widely use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, here is a step by step example (there may exist some more efficient ways to do the same thing).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
read_bin_value(const char *bin_str)
{
  unsigned int result=0;
  const int bin_len=8*(int)sizeof(result);
  const int str_len=(int)strlen(bin_str);
  assert(str_len&&(str_len<=bin_len));
  // extract bits from bin_str
  for(int i=0; i<str_len; ++i)
  {
    const unsigned int bit=(bin_str[i]!='0'); // assume '1' if not '0'
    result|=(bit<<(str_len-1-i)); // place bit
  }
  // extend sign bit
  const unsigned int sign_bit=(bin_str[0]!='0');
  for(int i=str_len; i<bin_len; ++i)
  {
    result|=(sign_bit<<i);
  }
  // interpret as signed value
  return (int)result;
}

int
main(void)
{
  const char *bin_str[]={"1011", "0011", "0", "1", "01", NULL};
  for(int i=0; bin_str[i]; ++i)
  {
    char dec_str[20];
    snprintf(dec_str, sizeof(dec_str), "%d", read_bin_value(bin_str[i]));
    printf("%s --> %s\n", bin_str[i], dec_str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that, according to two's complement, the binary representation of -3 (base 10) is not `"1011"` (I guess you supposed a signed integer was just an unsigned one with a sign bit, but it is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine how many bits representation you want to use and take the input as a string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char numberAsAString[65];
int wordSize;
int binToSignedInt(char* numberAsAString,int wordSize)
{
    int value=0,multi=1,i,upto=1; //"upto" means we will stop calculating the value before 1st element...as the 0th element is containing sign bit and it is not a part of the value
    if(wordSize>strlen(numberAsAString))upto=0; //But if the word size is larger than the signed bit is assumed to be zero and we are taking the whole input as the value
    for(i=strlen(numberAsAString)-1;i>=upto;i--)
    {
        if(numberAsAString[i]=='1') //simple bin to dec conversion
        {
            value=value+multi;
        }
        multi=multi*2;
    }
    if(upto==0)return value; //If allowed number of bits representation was larger then the number was positive...as 0 is assumed at the beginning of the representation
    //otherwise
    if(numberAsAString[0]=='1')return -value; //If sign bit is 1 the value is negative
    return value; //The value is positive if the signed bit is not one (or is 0)
}
int main()
{
    printf("Enter number: "); //Enter the number as a sting
    scanf("%s",numberAsAString);
    printf("Enter word size: "); //Enter how many bits representation you want to use
    scanf("%d",&wordSize);
    if(wordSize<strlen(numberAsAString)) //If the number is larger than the allowed bits representation than considering the input as an invalid input
    {
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Value in signed integer form: %d\n",binToSignedInt(numberAsAString,wordSize)); //Signed integer output
    return 0;
}
```