# Do I use >> to sign extend in c++?

Tags: c++, bit

If I wanted to sign extend a char containing 6 bits to 16 bits

char bits = 0x3F;

Do I do a left shift to shift by 8 bits ?

I am sorry I am not very good with bit shifting. Responses will be very much appreciated.

Comment: how about `short s = bits;` ? (or int16_t )

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili that depends on `char` being signed. Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is *implementation-defined*. If unsigned, that assignment will zero-extend, not sign-extend. So you need a type cast to ensure a sign-extended assignment: `int16_t s = static_cast<signed char>(bits);` Though, in this case, I guess it doesn't matter, since the sign for 6 bits will always be 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's right. Since OP mentioned they want to sign-extend, I figured that was a given. Unsigned types don't have a sign.

Comment: If bits is not a signed number, then zero-extending is actually what I want to do. If it is however a signed number, then sign extending is actually what I want to do

Comment: @ALaw so, you want to extend the 6th bit (the *logical* sign bit)? Because the 8th bit (the *actual* sign bit) will always be 0 in your example. Either way, you don't need any bit shifting to solve this

Comment: What if bits is 0x3F << 2? Then how do I sign extend this

Comment: @ALaw See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17719010/10147399).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sign extend a nine-bit number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814072/sign-extend-a-nine-bit-number-in-c)